# How do I increase the dimensions of a numpy int32 array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have an numpy int32 array called `a` that has shape `(4, 8, 3)`. I want to reshape this array to one that is of size `(4, 12, 3)`. How do I do that?

I have tried using `reshape`, but `reshape` requires that the array be the same size.

Comment: To be clear, I am willing to fill in any new spaces with 0s (or any default data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong but : a numpy array isn't supposed to be mutated this way.
When you do a reshape what you're actually doing is just changing the order/way in which the bytes/elements are read

What you want to do is create a new array that is bigger and contains the data of the previous array plus other stuff. You have to tell Numpy WHERE you want the new stuff and where you want the old stuff.

i.e:

```
new_array = np.zeros((4, 12, 3))
new_array[:, :8, :] = old_array
```

This example adds 4 additionnal "columns" on your array at the end of the second dimension.

Comment: `numpy.append` is another way to do the same thing.

Comment: Yes resize does something similar also but to bo honnest I don't really understand the purpose of these functions, I don't find it very explicit and I don't understand how you can choose where to put the filling values.