# Add an extra channel to specific dimension in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of shape

```
masks = encoded.reshape(n, h, w)
masks = np.expand_dims(masks, axis=3)
maskData = to_categorical(masks)
print(maskData.shape)

(16, 456, 684, 8)
```

I want to add an extra channel to 4th Dimension to make it to 9th, filled with zeros

```
n,h,w,c = maskData.shape
maskData.reshape(n,h,w, 9)
```

Seems to crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably make a new empty numpy array of wanted size and then fill it with the original data

```
n,h,w,c = maskData.shape
wanted_size = 9
new_mask_data = np.zeros([n,h,w,wanted_size])
new_mask_data[:,:,:,:c] = maskData
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question? But you have an multidimensional array with a certain shape and you want a new array with the same dimension in the first three dimension and 9 instead of 8 in the fourth dimension?

Comment: Here is another thread which solves that problem with a solution close to mine
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537772/how-do-i-increase-the-dimensions-of-a-numpy-int32-array